# Python email header extractor

Tags: python, powershell, email-spam, phishing, mass-emails

I have a simple piece of code with will look at a email header and pull out the date, from, to and subject of the email header. To do this i must put the email header into a .txt document in order for the code to read the header.

```
from email.parser import BytesHeaderParser
from glob import glob
import csv

fields = ['Date', 'From', 'To', 'Subject']

out = csv.writer(open('output.csv', 'w'))
out.writerow(["File name"]+fields)

parser = BytesHeaderParser()

for name in glob('*.msg'):
with open(name, 'rb') as fd:
msg = parser.parse(fd)
out.writerow([name]+[msg[f] for f in fields])
```

I want to be able to do this in a mass amount, so when dealing with large amounts of emails from the same 'phishing campaign' i can put all the .msg into one folder and run the script to extract the data i need.

Is this possible also willing to do the code in powershell.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Python to execute a command on every file in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120707/using-python-to-execute-a-command-on-every-file-in-a-folder)

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly suggest using one of the mime parsers built into Python for handling emails.  It's a relatively complicated format and doing naive things like you do above will tend to give you the wrong thing.  For example header lines can span multiple lines and you'd just get some of it with your code.

it should be a simple matter of doing:

```
from email.parser import HeaderParser
from glob import glob
import csv

fields = ['Date', 'From', 'To', 'Subject']

out = csv.writer(open('output.csv', 'w'))
out.writerow(["File name"]+fields)

parser = HeaderParser()

for name in glob('*.msg'):
  with open(name) as fd:
    msg = parser.parse(fd)
  out.writerow([name]+[msg[f] for f in fields])
```

Comment: gives me this? Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new.py", line 12, in <module>
    [msg[f] for f in fields])
TypeError: writelines() argument must be a sequence of strings

Comment: presumably some of those header fields don't exist.  maybe use a file format that makes that easier to handle?  CSV would be ideal for this!

Comment: Sorry dude i'm new to this really what do you mean?

Comment: so you saying to write to the CSV?

Comment: @Will updated to write to csv file… I'd suggest reading some Python/programming tutorials to get started

Comment: So i added the script and 3 .msg files to a folder and ran the script from the folder. I get an error. I have eddited the script to only look for the "From:" aspect. 

    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 2129: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: you might want to look at opening the file in "binary" mode and using a `BytesHeaderParser`.  character encoding can be difficult to get right and depends on a few system specific details.  might be worth reading some tutorials about that, also Python changed behavior a lot between version 2 and 3, so you'll need to make sure you're reading the right one.  Python 3 is much nicer if you have the choice!

Comment: i've added an encoder as reading online it can solve the issue   with open(name, encoding='utf8') as fd:

but the error seems to be with  msg = parser.parse(fd) when im tracing it back

Comment: depending on where they come from, it can be better to just treat the email as bytes (i.e. `open(name, 'rb')`) and then use use an email parser that does the right thing.  i.e. `…`gets encoded as  `=?UTF-8?B?4oCm?=` in a subject line which is separate from the underlying file's encoding.  which you want depends on what you do with it later

Comment: Ok so i updates the code (See update) i dont get any errors now but nothing goes to the file? is there anyway to see if the files are being read?

Comment: try googling for "Python debugging".  easiest is to add some `print` statements, otherwise look for an "interactive debugger".  stack overflow really isn't the best for these sorts of extended discussions, it's really about well defined questions and answers…